# Adding SCNLight inside SK3DNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am creating an `SK3DNode` inside an `SKScene`:

```swift
let ball: SK3DNode = {
    let scnScene = SCNScene()
    let ballGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 200)
    let ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ballGeometry)
    ballNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "wall")
    ballGeometry.materials = [material]

    let light = SCNLight()
    light.type = .omni
    light.color = UIColor.white
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = light

    scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)
    scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
    let node = SK3DNode(viewportSize: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000))
    node.scnScene = scnScene
    node.autoenablesDefaultLighting = false
    return node
}()
```

However, the sphere renders black. Tried it with or without the material. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sphere is manually placed at `(0, 0, 0)` and so is the light (default value). This means that the light is placed *inside* the sphere. This means that the surface of the sphere is facing away from the light source and thus isn't lit.